# How to scale already existing bitmap in android?

Tags: android

I have an already decoded bitmap that I would like to temporarily scale before drawing it on a canvas. So decoding a file and setting the size before is out of the question. I would like to keep the size of the existing bitmap and just scale it to be smaller before drawing it on the canvas. Is this posible?

using Matrix postScale(sx, sy, px, py) scales it correctly but doesn't position it right. And canvas.drawBitmap doesn't have an option with matrix and x & y position from what I can see.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
    final int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    final float scale = Math.min((float) width / (float) bitmapWidth,
            (float) height / (float) bitmapHeight);

    final int scaledWidth = (int) (bitmapWidth * scale);
    final int scaledHeight = (int) (bitmapHeight * scale);

    final Bitmap decoded = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(decoded);

    return decoded;
}
```

**Please note:** Pass the bitmap to scale and it's new height and width.

Comment: Can i draw this bitmap on a existing bitmap?? If yes, how? If NO what can be the possible solution for it?